# How to get the manufactured date information in Android?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2, dialer-codes

In old Nokia phones we get the manufacturer information and manufactured date, purchase date, no. of repairs done etc using the codes like `*#92702689#` , `*#0000#` and `*#06#`. While only the `*#06#` works since its mandatory to include this code by the manufacturer for showing the phone's IMEI number.

Is there any way or an adb command we can get those information in an Android phone? Atleast a way to get the manufactured date information. BTW, my Moto G2 is not rooted and running Android Lollipop 5.0.1.