# How to get the phone production date via ADB?

Tags: adb, samsung, hardware, samsung-galaxy-s-21

How can I get programmatically when the phone was manufactured?

Is there any framework, instrumentation or toolset like Windows [WMIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) that allows unequivocally get hardware parameters of the device?

I found [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120623/how-to-get-the-manufactured-date-information-in-android) but it is old, related to Motorola and has no answers, that is why I decided to ask a new one. I am seeking solution for Samsung phone, but vendor-agnostic way will be way better.

I know about [IMEI way](https://www.imei.info/news/how-know-production-date-my-mobile/) of checking the production date, but I want something more accurate that can be a double check.

Thanks.

Comment: [SO] [answers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956723/retrieve-android-device-manufactured-date-programmatically&ved=2ahUKEwjZyf3Cxr2AAxX7bmwGHfPRD78QFnoECB0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1P4mYAJYuOakimYsketnZQ) indicate that it's **not possible** to get the production date

Comment: For Samsung phones, this claims to give more info https://sndeep.info/en

Comment: Between the IMEI dates and the date when your phone appeared on geekbench [example](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_6a_listed_on_geekbench_with_tensor_chip-news-53444.php) could give you an approximate time window as a reasonable guess

Comment: **[Have you ever wanted to know the When the phone was manufactured?**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo.plus) - Samsung specific. I used this app a lot on Note 2 and found it good. IIRC it had device specific USSD codes and shortcuts to trigger them

Comment: Sadly, on Verizon Samsung phones all the USSD codes are stripped down, neither works

Comment: @beeshyams [good app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo.plus), and its output matched with what sndeep.info showed, but it is not free, this is its con. I can obtain the same info on multiple IMEI and serial checkers

Comment: I paid for the app and if you can find a way to share your serial number I can try checking for production date.

Comment: It doesn't give the manufacturing date on my Pixel 6a but from app description it should give for Samsung based on Serial number

Answer (score 0):

Grabbing the exact manufacturing date of a phone programmatically is not a straightforward task, and there is no standard framework or `API` in Android that provides this information aka  manufacturing date is not a an  `exposed parameter` in the device's hardware or software.

`IMEI` way you mentioned is one of the methods to get an approximate manufacturing date, but it's not always accurate,

The closest I have come to getting this info consistently on all Android versions  is this  ( `build.prop metadata` )

```
stat -c %y /system/build.prop
2020-12-31 20:30:00
```

On some Android devices this date maybe  stored in specific files  depending on   propriety flavor of Android used  ( e.g. MIUI or colors Android ) and Android version. Below  are just some pointer approaches to  dig it out , rummaging through usual places.

```
find /sys/fs/pstore/ /var/log/ /data/logs/  <your  other paths>   -type f -exec cat {} \; | grep -E "First boot|Installation date"'

 { cat /proc/kmsg /sys/fs/pstore/dmesg-ramoops-0; logcat ; } | grep -i -E "First boot|Installation date"
```

Comment: first, the build.prop metadata gives incorrect results, as this file frequently modified by enthusiasts on rooted devices. This confirmed by my tests, I ran this command on my Xiaomi Mi11i with custom ROM Xiaomi.eu and it returned 2008. But this phone was released in May 2021

Comment: second, executing commands in subshell {} is [not supported](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/shell_and_utilities/README.md) by adb shell, so your commands are unusable

Comment: @sun not so . I don t want the modified time. I get the creation time which remains unchanged. Yes I am rooted. Yes I did modify my prop and yes that date remained the same. Its a kind of hack situation you need to see proof in the  output date that you see as pudding

Comment: @sun all my command  work in adb shell. MOF I tested em there . But I wasnt able to find any data on my phone and didnt sweat it. So I just threw in the commands if you wanna try that approach . It sounds like you critique answers too much without seeing if they work in your env.

Comment: @sun Your poss right on that metdata. I didnt read your 1st comment.  Lets see if I can  dig up another hack. One thing clear as Niagara is - officially your going to be nay ed - you have to  find a hack that works

Comment: Of course I did the tests and tried applying the commands before writing the comment, [this](https://imgur.com/a/090o81q) and [this](https://imgur.com/a/DqC5lW2). Maybe the subshell works in the second command, not sure, maybe this is permissions error, but the first syntax with `find` is obviously wrong. `<your  other paths>` is not an answer for SE, I should not need to guess the answer from the thousands possible options

Comment: that is why I've thrown that as an approach..something  that can be built  upon . I test both on adb su prompt work well  but no luck getting the date

Answer (score -1):

It can be difficult and occasionally impossible to determine a phone's exact manufacturing date programmatically, especially on Android devices because of **privacy and security constraints**.
The manufacturing date of a phone is not directly accessible via a standard Android API or framework.
Using the `Build` class, you can get the build time as shown below:

```
val buildTime = Build.TIME
```

Remember that this represents the *`time at which the firmware was created`*, not the date the device was manufactured.

Comment: Note that even if the phone has never received any update the firmware build date may be far away from the hardware production date, as the firmware can be way older than the hardware. As the question is about a Galaxy S21 which receives regular [security] updates, the firmware build date will be totally different than the hardware production date.

Comment: Thats because its from chatgpt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).